# Android thread in non-activity class

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a class which will store a list of objects and will also populate this list from a database (via a cursor) This will happen when I instantiate the object. I want to populate the list on a separate thread and then set a flag in the class when the list is populated. Do I need to use a handler or is that only for the UI thread?

Thanks,
m

This seems to work for me:

```
public void pop(){
    mReadyToSearch = false;
    new Thread() {
        public void run() { final Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            Log.i(TAG, "Start Pop");

                            populateAnimalListFromCursor();
                            mReadyToSearch = true; 

                            final Long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; 
                            Log.i(TAG, "End Pop : "+ Long.valueOf(endTime)  +"ms");

                            }
        }.start();
}
```

Seems a bit simple but it loads the list and sets the state of the class which is all I need at the minute. Can anyone see a problem with this?

Thanks, m

Comment: Sorry, not very clear. The list is not a ListView it is just a List of Objects. The class will not be used for displaying anything on the UI it will only be used for scoring the items in the list against user input criteria.

Comment: do all worker stuff like storing item in list of object in AsyncTask's doInBackground() method. So its not block your UI and all complex things run in background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instantiate the object from somewhere on the UI-thread, the instantation will also be run on the UI-thread.

I suggest you add an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) (or a [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) could do it, if you don't need to update UI-components) as an inner class of your object to do the loading - this way it will be done from a  non-UI-thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), it simplifies using threads. However, you can use a [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) (or [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)) to populate the ListView, depending where your data is coming from.